# Listbox null pointer exception in zk

Tags: java, listbox, zk

I am trying to write a test-case without using a ZUL file for now. I have a very basic function with the following lines.

Class to initialize Listbox:

```
public class TestComposer {

    public void listboxTest(){

        ListModelList model = new ListModelList();
        Listbox lbOne = new Listbox();
        lbOne.setModel(model);
        lbOne.setMultiple(true);

        System.out.println(lbOne); 

        System.out.println(model); 

    }

}
```

Test-case

```
public class testSuit {
    static ZatsEnvironment env; 

    @BeforeClass
    public static void init() {
        System.out.println("Setting server space.");
        env = new DefaultZatsEnvironment("/main/webapp/WEB-INF");
        env.init("/main/webapp");           

    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void end() {
        env.destroy();
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        env.cleanup();
    }

    @Test
    public void test() {
        TestComposer tc = new TestComposer();

        tc.listboxTest();
    }
}
```

This piece of code will produce a null pointer exception. It shows that lbOne is null. Is there a way to use listbox without calling/using a ZUL file?

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException  at 
org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Events.postEvent(Events.java:383)     at 
org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Events.postEvent(Events.java:432)     at 
org.zkoss.zk.ui.event.Events.postEvent(Events.java:366)     at 
org.zkoss.zul.Listbox.postOnInitRender(Listbox.java:2501)   at 
org.zkoss.zul.Listbox.setModel(Listbox.java:2266)   at 
test.TestComposer.listboxTest(TestComposer.java:12)     at 
test.testSuit.test(testSuit.java:75)    at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)     at 
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at 
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)     at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)     at 
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)    at 
org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)     at 
org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)  at 
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)   at 
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)     at 
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)   at 
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)   at 
org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)   at 
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)     at 
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)     at 
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)   at 
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)     at 
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)    at 
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)   at 
org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)     at 
org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)   at 
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)     at 
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)  at 
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)  at 
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)  at 
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)   at 
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Line/trace of the NPE error

```
test.TestComposer.listboxTest(TestComposer.java:12) at test.testSuit.test(testSuit.java:75) at 
lbOne.setModel(model);
```

PS: I am using ZK web framework. I am using a testing tool that can't capture the traces in zats simulated environment. Thus, I want to directly call these methods without depending on ZUL files.

Comment: pretty odd that the first print shows `null`, because then the previous line `lbOne.setModel(model);` should throw a NPE

Comment: @AlexGreg, sorry for the confusion. You are right. It was throwing a NPE. I revised the code sample

Answer (score 0):

what about using this strategy:

```
public void listboxTest(){

    ListModelList model = new ListModelList();
    Listbox lbOne = new Listbox();
    lbOne.setModel(model);
    lbOne.setMultiple(true);

    System.out.println(lbOne); 

    System.out.println(model); 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it gives the same error.

Comment: weird..can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: I have updated the question with all the code and stack trace. Thanks

Comment: ZK version 6.0. I am trying to analyze something for that specific project. I am working on a testing project.

Answer (score 0):

1. your `TestComposer` should extend `SelectorComposer` if you develop in MVC pattern. Please read [MVC tutorial](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Getting_Started/Get_ZK_Up_and_Running_with_MVC)
2. you should test a composer with a zul instead of creating an instance by yourself.
   For example, you should apply the composer to a component and run ZATS client to visit the zul. Please read [First Mimic Test Case](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZATS_Essentials/Getting_Started/First_Mimic_Test_Case/JUnit_Example)